# Connection Pooling in sybase

Tags: ado.net, sybase, sap-ase

How to clear connection pool from dotnet(C#) once the process/connection is closed ? 
I am using sybase aseconnection , even after the connection is closed from ado.net , i could see some open connection in pool. Is there any way to clear those from dotnet code..Can anyone help me on this.

I am using sybase version ("Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19397 SMP ESD#5/P/ia64/HP-UX B.11.23/asear155/2568/64-bit/FBO/Fri").

Comment: I am using sybase version ("Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19397 SMP ESD#5/P/ia64/HP-UX B.11.23/asear155/2568/64-bit/FBO/Fri").

Comment: This seems to be more of an ado.net question, than a Sybase ASE question, so I've added the appropriate tags.

Comment: [Connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543.aspx) is generally handled by each ADO.NET provider and you shouldn't need to care about the connection states, as long as you correctly call `Dispose` on your `DbConnection` in your code. The managed providers for SQL Server and Oracle removes the connection from the pool after it's been inactive for an "extended period of time". I'm not sure about Sybase, but I would think that it follows the same pattern.

Comment: Do the lingering connections pose a problem for you? It's normal for applications using connections to leave idle connections behind, since opening a new physical connection is expensive. Does the number of connections stay at 6, or does the count increase over time? The default pool size settings for Sybase seems to be min: 20 and max: 100. This means that any connection that causes the pool size to exceed 20 will be physically closed when it's closed/disposed from code. If the number of active connections is 100, an exception will be thrown if you attempt to create more connections.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the API documentation on the Sybase page, you can control the lifetime of a connection in the pool by setting the Connection Lifetime property in the connection string. It defaults to 0, which means indefinately.

From the [AseConnection docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20066.0115/html/adonet/Asaconnection_apiref.htm):

> Connection Lifetime
>
> The time, in seconds, that connections can stay open. When a client
>   closes a connection that has reached or exceeded the defined
>   Connection Lifetime, before the driver closes the connection instead
>   of returning it to the connection pool. An idle connection is closed
>   and removed from the connection pool once it reaches the defined
>   Connection Lifetime.
>
> The default value of Connection Lifetime is 0, which indicates that
>   the connection can remain open for an indefinite amount of time.

A second interesting property is:

> Connection Idle Timeout
>
> The time, in seconds, that a connection can stay idle in the connection pool before the driver closes the connection. A value of 0 allows connections to stay idle for an indefinite amount of time.

You should be able to set them using this connection string (1 minute lifetime and idle timeout):

```
"Server=srv;Port=5000;uid=u;pwd=p;Connection Lifetime=60;Connection Idle Timeout=60;"
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments . But my scenario is little different. We have a web app which provides access to nearly 250 DB servers. Every time when i give access to user say 60 servers in count , after giving access , i could see around 5 to 6 connections open in each and every server. How to clear these connections once the process is complete.  Even when every process completes am doing connection.close() , but still there are few left out in pool.

Comment: If you want the connections to be closed immediately after you're done with them, the only solution as I see it is to disable connection pooling (this is done by setting the connection string property `pooling` to false). Be aware that this can degrade your performance. If you don't want to disable pooling completely, setting a reasonably low Connection Lifetime (a couple of minutes), should close the connections as well. Upon a second look at the docs, I also saw the ConnectionIdleTimeout and edited that info into my answer.